# How to get reference to current route from controller?

Tags: ember.js, discourse

I have a controller (`KbRelatedGroupController`) that is loaded via a `{{render}}` helper in a template.

In the controller's action, if I do `this.get('target')`, it returns a reference to the parent controller for the page (`KbShowController`).

If I call `.target` on that, I get a reference to `Discourse.Router`, which is no good to me.

What I want is a reference to a `KbShowRoute`, and that is what I expected since `.target` is supposed to produce the Route when called from a controller is it not?

Really confused here. Why is it so hard to get a reference to the current route from a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I see it, you're not supposed to. You can let the action bubble up to the route:

```
App.KbShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    ...
    actions: {
        something: function() {
            console.log('called second');
        }
    }
});

App.KbShowController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    ...
    actions: {
        something: function() {
            console.log('called first');
        }
    }
});
```

see [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling)

You could:

1. Handle one part of the action in the controller, and let it bubble to the route by not returning anything in the controller's action handler
2. Let the route handle the action (by not adding the action to your controller's action hash) and from the route use `this.controllerFor(this.routeName).sendAction('..', ...)` to call a different action (or part of the action) in the controller.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I guess this makes sense. I ended up doing something like what you said. Thanks!